# Find a function

Tags: functions, derivatives, mathematical-modeling, applications, biology

It's a cuttout from Rempe article "A mathematical model of the sleep/wake cycle" about a function which I don't understand how to describe: $h(t)$ decays exponentially while the system is asleep
and increases while awake. We scale the variables so that the system is defined to
be asleep if $x_A < 0$ and awake if $x_A > 0$. Then $h(t)$ satisfies $h' = α_h(h_{max} − h)$
while awake (when $x_A > 0$) and $h' = −β_hh$ while asleep (when $xA < 0$). Here,
$α_h, β_h$ and $h_{max}$ are constants. Also, a period of cycle last 24h, 16h system is awake and sleeps for 8h. 

 How to describe a function $h(t)$ in one equation? I think it should be somehow related with $H_{\infty}(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x/0.01}}$ as it widely used in this article. 

 Here are links to original article and some corrections [Article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26321676_A_mathematical_model_of_the_sleepwake_cycle), [corrections](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26321676_A_mathematical_model_of_the_sleepwake_cycle) . $h(t)$ mentioned on $620$page.

Comment: Is there no period/ interval for sleep or for being awake in a cycle?

Comment: @Narasimham just mentioned that sleeps for 8hours and awake for 16hours, whole cycle period 24h.

Comment: Represents some blood constituent  level? You can improve the question.

Comment: Nothing told about blood, this sleep-wake is based on neurons. Here is full article, this function described on 620page : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26321676_A_mathematical_model_of_the_sleepwake_cycle, and some corrections to it: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26321676_A_mathematical_model_of_the_sleepwake_cycle. I'm actually very new in this field. @Narasimhan

Comment: Do you expect a closed form expression to exist? It seems like the function will have discontinuous derivatives and exponential behaviour so a useful closed form seems unlikely.

Comment: @David I see, but I need to describe it somehow in my thesis and write a matlab code for it. Do you have any ideas how to do it?